# Codeigniter SaaS app - Dynamic database selection on cli cron job

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, saas

I have developed a multi-tenant app in Codeigniter as guided in  http://anantgarg.com/2013/06/10/build-a-php-saas-app-from-scratch and everything works fine. now I want to add cron job functionality to my app. while searching on the web i found few links 
https://www.heatware.net/programming-php/manage-cron-jobs-database-codeigniter
https://glennstovall.com/writing-cron-job-in-codeigniter
and created a Codeigniter library as well

```
class CronRunner {
var $ci;
var $ci_cron_db;
var $ci_cron_table;
public function __construct() {

    $this->ci = & get_instance();

    $this->ci->load->helper('url');
    $this->ci->load->library('user_agent');
    $this->ci->load->library('session');
    $this->ci->load->database();

    $this->ci_cron_db = $this->ci->db;
    $this->ci_cron_table = 'crn_crons';

}

private function calculateNextRun($obj) {
    return (time() + $obj->interval_sec);
}

public function run() {
    $query = $this->ci_cron_db->where('is_active', 1)->where('now() >= next_run_at OR next_run_at IS NULL', '', false)->from($this->ci_cron_table)->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        $env = getenv('CI_ENV');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $cmd = "export CI_ENV={$env} && {$row->command}";
            $this->ci_cron_db->set('next_run_at', 'FROM_UNIXTIME(' . $this->calculateNextRun($row) . ')', false)->where('id', $row->id)->update($this->ci_cron_table);
          $output = shell_exec($cmd);
            $this->ci_cron_db->set('last_run_at', 'now()', false)->where('id', $row->id)->update($this->ci_cron_table);
        }
    }
}
}
```

and i have achieved dynamic DB selection using a custom config file like below

```
$host = $ci->input->server('HTTP_HOST');
```

using **$host** ill go through my master database and load the client specific database.

```
//Database Config
$config['app_host'] = $app_db_host;
$config['app_database'] = $app_db_database;
$config['app_username'] = $app_db_username;
$config['app_password'] = $app_db_password;
```

in my database.php

```
$ci = get_instance();

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => $ci->config->item('app_host'),
    'username' => $ci->config->item('app_username'),
    'password' => $ci->config->item('app_password'),
    'database' => $ci->config->item('app_database'),
```

till this everything works fine.

now i need to achieve the same from command line for my cron job functionality. as im trying to invoke the script from command line not from a webserver i couldn't get 'HTTP_HOST' value. unfortunately, till now my app fully depends on 
'HTTP_HOST' for client selection.

any ideas or approaches to achieve this both on command line as well as webserver?

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the SaaS tool i manage, in the crontab i have one line per customer

```
1 * * * *        php /home/www/cron.php <customer-token1>
1 * * * *        php /home/www/cron.php <customer-token2>
1 * * * *        php /home/www/cron.php <customer-token3>
```

So each time i have a new customer, it adds a new line in crontab with the customer token or customer name, like you want...